# Is there a reliable way to determine if a browser tab or window is inactive or not in focus?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I've got a javascript timer that is making XMLHTTP requests on a constant basis (once every 10 seconds).  I'd love to be able to pause the timer when the window or tab loses focus.

I'm fully aware of the `onFocus` and `onBlur` events on the `window` object, but they don't fire reliably across all browsers.  For instance, [in Safari, tabs don't trigger the events](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/webkit-unassigned/2009-February/101708.html).

Simple code below distills the functionality I'm looking for:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.2/prototype.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="console"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onfocus = function(event) {
        $('console').insert('Window gained focus<br />');
      }

      window.onblur = function(event) {
        $('console').insert('Window lost focus<br />');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone out there have a technique for determining when a browser window or tab loses/gains focus that works across across all popular browsers?

Comment: in my experience, this is not solvable using flash.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099063/detecting-embedded-object-focus-in-safari

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above code is working fine in `Safari v3.0.4` (WebKit 530+), the bug has been resolved it seems. I've checked it in `Google Chrome v3.0.195.27` and it has the same Safari bug, although it has a newer version of WebKit.

Comment: You're correct that recent versions of Safari do handle this, and Chrome does not.  I'm just going to say that for my purposes, support of 3 out of the top 4 ain't that bad.

Comment: Chrome v3.0.195.38 is behaving strangely. It fires the events on tab switch but only when at least one window switch occurs.

Answer (score 2):

There is another Stack Overflow question regarding this topic. They didn't address the tabbed browsing issue there. They do give a link which goes into some detail, although without using jquery.

[Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

I don't think focus/blur events work with tabbed browsing in Safari at all. Some people have suggested mouse events, like mouseleave/mouseenter for this.

I've got some UI issues like this myself, so if I discover anything I'll follow up here.

Answer (score 0):

My previous desperate attempts to find such a thing have led me to conclude that there is no such animal.

Oh, how I would love to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    // Adapted slightly from Sam Dutton
    // Set name of hidden property and visibility change event
    // since some browsers only offer vendor-prefixed support
    var hidden, state, visibilityChange; 
    if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "hidden";
        visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
        state = "visibilityState";
    } else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "mozHidden";
        visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
        state = "mozVisibilityState";
    } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "msHidden";
        visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
        state = "msVisibilityState";
    } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "webkitHidden";
        visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
        state = "webkitVisibilityState";
    }

    // Add a listener that constantly changes the title
    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, function() {
        document.title = document[state];
    }, false);

    // Set the initial value
    document.title = document[state];

</script>
```

Comment: It s nice to provide code that could help solving a problem. But in this site we expect answers to explain the why and the how. Please add some precisions to your post.

Answer (score -1):

One thing to consider is that **tab** `focus`/`blur` events being blocked by browser vendors is possibly a way to protect users. Some browsers allow `alert()`-style popups (and even, I believe, a `focus()` method) to cause a tab to regain focus. Blocking the `focus`/`blur` events for tab switching could be akin to protection against, for example, unrequested popups and window sizing/positioning/closing.

Comment: He means listening for those events, not firing them himself.